# How to write a factory for this model in django using factory_boy?

Tags: django, django-models, django-tests, factory-boy

I have a model in my app that contains many_to_many fields on the same model but with a filter. To be more clear this is what I have:

```
class Places(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField('User')
     common_kwargs = dict(to='places.Place', blank=True)
     place1_kwargs = dict(
     common_kwargs.items() + {
        'limit_choices_to': {'site__token': 'site1'},
        'related_name': '%(app_label)s_%(class)s_place1',
        'verbose_name': _('Place 1')
        }.items()
    )
    place1= models.ManyToManyField(**place1_kwargs )

       place2_kwargs = dict(
       common_kwargs.items() + {
        'limit_choices_to': {'site__token': 'site2'},
        'related_name': '%(app_label)s_%(class)s_place2',
        'verbose_name': _('Place 2')
        }.items()
    )
    place2 = models.ManyToManyField(**place2_kwargs)
```

and this is `Place` model in `places` app :

```
class Place(models.Model):
     site= models.ForeignKey(Site, verbose_name=_('Site'))
     name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'),unique=True, max_length=255, db_index=True)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('City'), null=True)
```

And this is Site model :

```
 class Site(models.Model):
     token = models.CharField(_('Token'), max_length=255, unique=True, editable=False)
     name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
```

I tried to create a Factory for `Places` model but I didnt know how to set the filter of `Site`?

Could Somebody help me on this ?? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the SiteFactory as well and use a `SubFactory` because it is a `ForeignKey`. Hope this helps:

```
class PlacesFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Places

        site = factory.SubFactory(SiteFactory)

    @factory.post_generation
    def place1(self, create, extracted):
        if not create:
            return
        if extracted:
            for place in extracted:
                self.place1.add(place)
```

Here you can find the official documentation of [SubFactory](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.SubFactory).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I create the two m2m  fields `place1` and `place2`  of `Places` model ?

Comment: @pietà I updated the answer :) You should use the `factory.post_generation` decorator.

Comment: @pietà for each M2M field you should create a method.